# Display image on a button when user clicks the button

Tags: java, image, javafx, gridview

I am trying to put an image on a button when the user clicks that button. The button are arranged in a gridpane layout with similar type of buttons. The problem is that the button gets resized I don't know why.

This is part of my Controller.java

```
        //box row where button is clicked
        int row = GridPane.getRowIndex((Node) actionEvent.getSource());
        //box column where button is clicked
        int column = GridPane.getColumnIndex((Node) actionEvent.getSource());
        if (grid.markGrid(row, column, playerPlaying))
        {
            //set mark on the Button
            Image mark;
            if (playerPlaying == Player.PLAYER1)
                mark = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("x.png"));
            else
                mark = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("circle.png"));
            Button buttonClicked = (Button) actionEvent.getSource();
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mark);
            imageView.setFitHeight(buttonClicked.getHeight());  
            imageView.setFitWidth(buttonClicked.getWidth());
            buttonClicked.setGraphic(imageView);
```

This is part of my fxml file

```
   <GridPane fx:id="buttonsGrid">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
        </rowConstraints>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="2" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" styleClass="grid-button"
                prefWidth="150" prefHeight="150" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
                onAction="#gridClick" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
    </GridPane>
```

Here is the image of resized grid

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the image? The buttons on the right are cropped? Also, is your prefWidth the width of your image? I would suggest using a blank image that is the same size as your x's and o's so when you switch images it doesn't affect the layout.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: The button naturally has some padding, etc. So if you make the image the same size as the button, the button will need to grow to accommodate the image and the padding.

Comment: @matt I tried using blank image of size of button and also resized x and o images to same size of the button but still when I click the button it increases in size.

Comment: @James_D How can I remove this padding

Comment: Override the [default CSS](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css). But your buttons will look strange; it's the borders and padding that give the effect of a button being pressed, etc.

Comment: Much better to use @matt's suggestion. Don't use a blank image the size of the button, though, use a blank image the same size as the other images.

Comment: Or, another solution is to put *both* image views in a stack pane in each button, but call `setVisible(false)` on them. Then to make one of them appear, call `setVisible(true)` on the appropriate image. That's the approach I used [here](https://github.com/james-d/TicTacToe) (though I used labels instead of images and didn't use buttons).

Comment: @James_D Using blank image of same size of as the other images did not work, as the button still increase in size.

Comment: @James_D Putting both image views in stack pane in each button worked for me. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: If you get a chance, you should make an answer. Sounds like a decent solution and probably will be a somewhat common problem.

Comment: @Vishal for single buttons use button.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));